# How to make responsive dropdown elements in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I heve some problems with making UI in Unity3d.
I have a dropdown element with 5 DDN items. This is original structure of DDN.

[image]

But on wide screen DDN items not responsive(2736x1824).

[image]

This is on FreeAcpect screen.

[image]

I want to make an elements responsive, but unity don't make it itself.
I try to set BestFit checkbox of Text element but no results.
[image]

Comment: Probably because the text is hitting the `Max Size` on large screens and stops getting bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a `Dropdown` with **default** properties and it is showing responsive behavior for bigger resolutions as well, as expected.
What you might be missing is the `UI Scale Mode` in `Canvas Scaler` component.

[image]

Also see
[Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html).